# Samsung Smart TV Javascript Application with AF2.0

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv, application-framework

I have created an application for my Samsung TV 2011 (Maple 6.0).
It is a Javascript Web App that does not depend on anything other than jquery, I handle navigation and remote key events myself with my own functions; I use in combination with TVKeyValue.js and Widget.js.

Now I am trying to play video. On the emulators up to 2013 (The oldest emulator available it seems) it works fine with video.js. It looks like it is not supported in the Maple.

However, I could get video to work if I include the Samsung Apps Framework:

I could get the video to play, however I need to add the Scene folders and app.json in order for the app to run. Then I could play my video. The problem is that it breaks the standard javascript code. JSON is not defined, html data attributes do not work.

So my question is, how can I maintain my application as a javascript webapp, while still being able to play video via the 2011 tv running maple?
HTML4 is whats supported so video tags do not work, and flash it says plugin required. So there does not seem to be any video solutions for non AF samsung apps.

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung devices is better solution then video tag using SEF player
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=API00005&FileName=Player_29.html
(Player item)